# Function to calculate bmi and return a string

Tags: javascript

I am taking an online course for which I have been presented with a practice problem. I am to build a bmi (body mass index) calculator which returns a value letting the user know what their bmi is.

I attempted to solve this using an if statement but the validator throws an error saying my solution is incorrect. Can anybody see what may be wrong with my code?

```
var interpretation = "";

function bmiCalculator (weight, height) {
    bmi = weight / Math.pow(height, 2);

    if (bmi < 18.5) {
        interpretation = "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are underweight";
    } else if (bmi => 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9) {
        interpretation = "Your BMI is " + bmi +", so you have a normal weight";
    } else {
        interpretation = "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are overweight";
    }

   return interpretation;
}
```

Comment: You haven't declared `bmi` (you can do that with `let bmi` inside the function. You should either declare a local variable inside the function where you store the value for a common return, or use multiple return statements. Do NOT change the value of a global variable.

Comment: A better approach is to test if the value is lower (like you do) and in the next if-statement if is higher, and then in the last else have what is left in the middle. Whith this you only need to specify the values at one place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Template string or string concatenation to add `bmi` value in final output

***Here's an example how to do it with Template string :-***

```
var interpretation = "";

function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
    bmi = weight / Math.pow(height, 2);

    if (bmi < 18.5) {
        interpretation = `Your BMI is ${bmi}, so you are underweight`;
    } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9) {
        interpretation = `Your BMI is ${bmi}, so you have a normal weight`;
    } else {
        interpretation = `Your BMI is ${bmi}, so you are overweight`;
    }

    return interpretation;
}
```

You code can be further improved to this

```
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
    let bmi = weight / Math.pow(height, 2);
    let interpretation = `Your BMI is ${bmi}, so you `
    if (bmi < 18.5) {
        interpretation += `are underweight`;
    } else if (bmi < 25) {
        interpretation += `have a normal weight`;
    } else {
        interpretation += `are overweight`;
    }

    return interpretation;
}
```

Comment: Ahh rookie mistake haha, I went ahead and changed it so that I'm using concatenation, however it still doesnt solve my problem, I believe there is something wrong with the calculation though the formula seems to be correct.

Comment: Improve it further with `if (bmi < 18.5) {} else if (bmi >= 25) {} else {}`

Comment: A bmi of 24.91 is still normal. Change it to `< 25`.

Comment: @SufianJaved are you sure about the units you're using is proper or not ? cause formula is fine, as `some` mentioned in comment correct you range too

Comment: @some Gotcha! Gotta keep an eye out for these little details :p

Comment: @CodeManiac Improve it further with: let interpretation = `Your BMI is ${bmi}, so you ` and then update the strings in the if-statements.

Comment: @some completely missed that bmi is same in all if-else lamo, will update it

Comment: @CodeManiac Easy to miss. :) One more thing: could you please indent the code too? It will make it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys! I believe the issue is with the units because it is returning under weight for all combinations of weight and height, trying to figure out what may be the issue here.

Comment: @some yeah sure

Comment: @CodeManiac that definitely makes the code much more concise :)

Comment: Solved it! You can find my solution below :) @some

Comment: Solved it! You can find my solution below :) @CodeManiac

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the above comments, here is a simplified solution that will do the same thing:

```
function calc(weight, height) { 
  var bmi = weight/(height*height);
  var bmis=bmi.toFixed(2);
  return `Your BMI is ${bmis}, so you `+
       (bmi<18.5?'are underweight'
      : bmi<25  ?'have a normal weight'
      :          'are overweight'); }
```

I added rounding to two digits with `.toFixed(2)` as nobody will be interested in an answer with a 13 digit precision.

While `Math.pow(height,2)` is mathematically correct, the direct product `height*height` can be calculated with much less effort.

(It doesn't matter in this example but it can be important in cases where you run multiple iterations or work on large arrays.)

Comment: Haha yeah I realized that after and made the change as well! Thank you though :)

Answer (score -1):

So I was finally able to get it to work with this:

```
function bmiCalculator (weight, height) {
    var bmi = weight/(height*height);
    if (bmi > 24.9){
        return "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are overweight.";
    }
    if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <=24.9){
        return "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you have a normal weight.";
    }
    if (bmi < 18.5){
        return "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are underweight.";
    }
}
```

Turns out the order of the if statements matters a ton in this case!

Comment: You are using the same vale in several if-statements, That is not good code, Since you are now using return statements you can use `if (bmi < 18.5) { return "underweight"; if bmi < 25" { return "normal"} return "owerweight"`

Comment: @some
gotcha, ill fix that up!